# Node.js using multer, res.file returns undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
const app = require('express')();
const PORT = 8080;
const multer = require('multer')
bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.listen(
    PORT,
    () => console.log(`it's alive on http://localhost:${PORT}`)
)

app.post('/user/self/pic', (multer({
    dest: '../uploads'
  }).single('image'), (req,res) => {
   
     console.log(req.file)
  
  }))
```

I'm building this most basic app using node.js. There's no front end implementation as our instructor doesn't allow any. Normally req.file will return basic info of the post request, but I tried many times and I'm getting undefined.

Comment: I'm using postman to send a post request

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. It's really hard to tell why a request isn't being parsed as expected when you don't provide any details of the request.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a miss using in parentheses, try it:

```js
app.post('/user/self/pic', multer({ dest: '../uploads' }).single('image'), (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.file);
});
```

And it is a better version:

```js
const uploader = multer({ dest: '../uploads' }).single('image');
app.post('/user/self/pic', uploader, (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.file);
});
```